# Pandas create a unique id for each row based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataset where one of the column is as below. I'd like to create a new column based on the below condition.

For values in column_name, if 1 is present, create a new id. If 0 is present, also create a new id. But if 1 is repeated in more than 1 continuous rows, then id should be same for all rows. The sample output result can be seen below.

```
column_name
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
0
0
1

column_name -- ID
1 -- 1
0 -- 2
0 -- 3
1 -- 4
1 -- 4
1 -- 4
1 -- 4
0 -- 5
0 -- 6
1 -- 7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say your Series is

```
s = pd.Series([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Then you can use:

```
>>> ((s != 1) | (s.shift(1) != 1)).cumsum()
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    4
5    4
6    4
7    5
8    6
9    7
dtype: int64
```

This checks that either the current entry is not 1, or that the previous entry is not 1, and then performs a cumulative sum on the result.

Comment: Damn that's elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially leveraging the fact that a 1 in the Series lagged by another 1 should be treated as part of the same group, while every 0 calls for an increment. One of four things will happen:

1) 0 with a preceding 0 : Increment by 1

2) 0 with a preceding 1 : Increment by 1

3) 1 with a preceding 1 : Increment by 0

4) 1 with a preceding 0: Increment by 1

```
(df['column_name'] + df['column_name'].shift(1)).\ ## Creates a Series with values 0, 1, or 2 (first field is NaN)
fillna(0).\ ## Fills first field with 0
isin([0,1]).\ ## True for cases 1, 2, and 4 described above, else False (case 3) 
astype('int').\ ## Integerizes it
cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    4
5    4
6    4
7    5
8    6
9    7
```

Answer (score 1):

At this stage I would just use a regular python for loop

```
column_name = pd.Series([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])

ID = [1]

for i in range(1, len(column_name)):
    ID.append(ID[-1] + ((column_name[i] + column_name[i-1]) < 2))

print(ID)

>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And then you can assign ID as a column in your dataframe

Comment: My apology for the downvote - Python loops are not the way to go in Pandas, unless there is really no other feasible choice.

Comment: That's a fair point, and thanks for providing an explanation for the downvote. Personally I can't find these super-pandas solution, and for me a for-loop is more intuitive. But my perspective is probably going to change as I learn more pandas.

Comment: Thanks for taking it in good spirits! It is just meant to convey that loops should be avoided, and is not directed against you. All the best in learning more pandas.